# GLMER, dados longitudinais, fator aleatorio, Binomial

Tags: r

Eu estou utilizando a função `glmer` do pacote `lme4`. A minha resposta é binomial.

Tenho 5 Escolas, com aproximadamente 100 professores, sendo que um professor não trabalha  em mais de um escola, possuo 5 informações longitudinais para cada professor.

A minha duvida é se utilizo:

`(1|escola/prof) ou (1 | escola) + (1 | prof) ou (1|prof/escol)`.

Ou estou pensando errado e é de outra forma?

Comment: Caro Cleber, vou votar para fechar a sua pergunta pois ela não é sobre programação. Acredito que você já tenha lido a tabela da página 6 deste link: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf que explica o que cada um desses comandos significa. A partir daí o problema passa a ser de estatística o que foge do escopo do site. O meu palpite é de que    qualquer um dos três será muito parecido uma vez que nenhum professor dá aula em duas escolas. No entanto, acredito que o terceiro não faça muito sentido (olhando pela hierarquia).

Comment: A minha sugestão é usar o primeiro: cada escola tem um intercepto aleatório e cada professor tem uma variação aleatória dentro da escola.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário e pelo link.